# Rails 5 not saving data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

After bashing away at this for two days, I'm completely stumped. I can't seem to save any data for any models that include this (outlined below) or anything I added afterward.

I have a migration that looks like this:

```
class CreateScenarios < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
 def change
  create_table :scenarios do |t|
  t.string :title
  t.text :description
  t.string :scenariotype
  t.references :activity, foreign_key: true
  t.timestamps
   end
 end
end
```

My schema:

```
create_table "scenarios", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "title"
t.text "description"
t.string "scenariotype"
t.bigint "activity_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.index ["activity_id"], name: "index_scenarios_on_activity_id"
end
```

Model looks like this:

```
class Scenario < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pages
  belongs_to :activities
end
```

In my controller, I have these params set:

```
def scenario_params
  params.require(:scenario).permit(:title, :description, :scenariotype, :activity_id)
end
```

The new method looks like this:

```
def new
   @scenario = Scenario.new
   @activity = Activity.find(params[:activity])
end
```

And the create method looks like this:

```
def create
   @scenario = Scenario.new(scenario_params)
   @activity = Activity.find(@scenario.activity_id)
   @scenario.save
   redirect_to new_page_path(scenario: @scenario.id)
end
```

When I try to save a record, even in the console, from this migration or any later migrations, it won't save and rolls back because it isn't autoincrementing. So running something like this:

```
scenario=Scenario.new(:activity_id =>1, :title =>"asfdasdf", :scenariotype=>"Teaching", :description=>"asdfadsf")
```

results in something like this

```
<Scenario id: nil, title: "asfdasdf", description: "asdfadsf", scenariotype: "Teaching", activity_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

And then it rolls back because it's missing an id.

I've dropped and recreated the databases. I thought something might be wrong with a previous migration, but those both work just fine. I'm hoping I'm missing something incredibly straightforward and stupid, but I'm just not seeing it. Database is Postgres.

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Do you have a form of some sort for @scenario ?

Comment: Do you have an existing Postgresql table called Activity table before running the migration for creating the Scenario table?

Comment: Do `@scenario.save!` instead and then paste the error/warning above.

Comment: Just another random guess, most likely unrelated but sometimes Rails cannot guess the correct plural form of a word, e.g. "love" => "lofe" instead of "loves". In these case, we need to tell Rails the correct plural form.

Comment: Can you give us the validations error thats cause the rollback ? Write `scenario=Scenario.new(:activity_id =>1, :title =>"asfdasdf", :scenariotype=>"Teaching", :description=>"asdfadsf")` then write `scenario.errors.full_messages` and give us the result here

Answer (score 1):

You have mistake in your Scenario model - when setting `belongs_to` association, singular form should be used. So instead of `belongs_to :activities` your model should look like:

```
class Scenario < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pages
  belongs_to :activity
end
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you - the Activity model did exist, but I was using the plural. Knew it was something I was just overlooking.

Comment: I tried to upvote, btw, but I don't have enough points to count - I'm so sorry - that was super helpful!